# Mistakenly used rm - rf in / but cancelled .How to recover now.?

Tags: server, data-recovery, chroot, data-loss, rescue-mode

I have unknowningly  used rm -rf in the ubuntu 18  / and cancelled soon .. within that moment some folders for deleted including **/bin /sbin /opt /etc** .
But we still have **/usr /lib / home /root /var** and others  and **luckily we were running some applications on the server which is still operational and running fine** for now but we are not able to access server .... My question is how do I recover it and if I boot in rescue mode will I be able to access data ...we need data on priority ... This server is remote

Comment: Did you run this as root/sudo? If so, you are going to need to reinstall. This is a fatal mistake.

Comment: Yes as root I have used the command ...but my application is working fine .I am not able to access the server ..so recovery is priority now ...can I recover using rescue mode

Comment: How do you normally access the server? Can you ssh in to it? You need to obtain access in order to do anything. If your server is inaccessible by normal methods, who has access to it? If this is a commercial hosting provider, they may have a service that gives you access to files.

Comment: I normally do ssh,but since I am not able to do ssh I booted in rescue mode which my hosting provider had that option .so I can access the server through rescue mode ..so I mounted my partition and my public  storage box to that  and copying all data ..